# How to reduce the file size of a video recorded through my iOS app on a phone

Tags: ios, video, compression

I am making an iOS app (Android soon) that involves users recording videos on their phones through the app. But I need the app to reduce the default size of those videos so that when they are uploaded to my server less bandwidth is used and it uploads faster. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Compress your video and then send that compress video data to your server .

Comment: Himanshu, that is what I am trying to do, but I need a script that will compress the video optimally as soon as it is recorded by the user. That is what I am looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code hope your task done.

```
- (void)convertVideoToLowQuailty:(NSURL*)inputURL 
                                       outputURL:(NSURL*)outputURL 
                                         handler:(void (^)(AVAssetExportSession*))handler
    {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:outputURL error:nil];
        AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:inputURL options:nil];
        AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality];
        exportSession.outputURL = outputURL;
        exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
        [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^(void) 
        {
            handler(exportSession);
            [exportSession release];
        }];
    }

    - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info

    {   
        NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
        NSURL *outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users/Hems/Desktop/output.mov"];
        [self convertVideoToLowQuailty:videoURL outputURL:outputURL handler:^(AVAssetExportSession *exportSession)
         {
             if (exportSession.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted)
             {
                 printf("completed\n");
             }
             else
             {
                 printf("error\n");

             }
         }];

    }
```

Comment: thanks. I will send this to my current dev to see if that works for me.

Comment: I found some info the following links. Thoughts?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-video-compression-library-is-used-by-WhatsApp

https://7labs.heypub.com/mobile/compress-video-android-ios-wp.html

Comment: Sorry. That was supposed to be 2 links SHIFT+ENTER still put them on one line. Here they are separately:

Comment: quora.com/What-video-compression-library-is-used-by-WhatsApp

Comment: @Rob don't know what kind of library whatsApp use but with this above code my work done so i use this one .

Comment: @Rob your above link is one application that convert your video in small size .