# Issue in playing Video URL in MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have to compress the video size in my app and play that compressed video in  `MPMoviePlayerController`.I am using `AVURLAsset` to compress that video and after compressing i m getting a Output URL and when i am playing that URL it shows me this **`Err0r:-'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'property storage cannot find expected per-thread storage data`**

Here is the code

```
 [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:outputURL error:nil];

    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:inputURL options:nil]; 

    AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality];

     exportSession.outputURL = outputURL; 
exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;


      [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^(void) { handler(exportSession);


         }];
```

What to do to resolve this issue.
Help me out

Comment: Please post your code, so that we can help you.

Comment: @RamkrishnaSharma refer my this answer for compose video and play it http://stackoverflow.com/a/40012857/6656894

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38671351/6656894 for complete MPMoviePlayerController see this answer

Comment: please post code snippet

Comment: @RamkrishnaSharma [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:outputURL error:nil];
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:inputURL options:nil];

AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality];
exportSession.outputURL = outputURL;
exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;

[exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^(void)
 {
     handler(exportSession);
 }];   These lines are for compressing video